# Foreach loop with json data laravel

Tags: json, excel, laravel, foreach

I want to make a table in html with json data using laravel excel, the data looks like this

```
4 => {
    +"id": 5
    +"date": "2020-1-3"
    +"grade": "7"
    +"nama": "["bryan","anderson"]"
    +"status": "["active","active"]"
}
```

the excel file output i was hoping for is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR8Uw.png). **Status** fill the column based on dates and if there is no data in particular date the column will filled with "-". I tried a foreach loop I found here, but did not have any luck.

I call the data with `$reports`, for example `$reports->status` will return `["active","active"]` and so on.

This is the code i am working on

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            @for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++)
                <th>{{ $i }}</th>
            @endfor
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($reports as $rp)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                    <!--INSERT DATA HERE-->
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

dd($reports) return =

```
array:2 [▼
0 => {#455 ▼
    +"id": 17
    +"date": "2021-01-03"
    +"grade": "7"
    +"nama": "["bryan","anderson"]"
    +"status": "["active","active"]"
    +"created_at": "2021-01-23 05:33:27"
    +"updated_at": "2021-01-23 05:33:27"
  }
  1 => {#1414 ▶}
]
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dd($reports)` to your question?

Comment: updated in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this following code;
    <table border=1>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @php $index=1; @endphp
                                @foreach ($reports as $rp)
                                    @foreach ($rp->nama as $key => $val)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $index }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $val }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ optional($rp->status)[$key] }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @php $index++; @endphp
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: the code throws an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: check now, error because answer was collection object not array. so, I have updated answer. now, check if still issue then share output of dd($reports).

Comment: now it says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in this line "@foreach ($rp->name as $key => $val)" $rp->name is the problem and i don't know what's wrong

Comment: Please share whole  output of dd($reports) so I can help you.

Comment: There is typo 'name' inplace of 'nama'. Can you try again..if still not work then add image of error screen as well as share sample data (as text file) to make table/listing

Comment: created new database format and it's working fine right now, thx for the help